# Difference between "pangalactic" and "transgalactic"?

Tags: differences, word-usage, prefixes

I am building a game and trying to give some fancy names to some objectives in my game.

So, I was wondering about the difference between the words *pangalactic* and *transgalactic*?

Does any of them mean something that is spawning across multiple galaxies? I am looking for a set of 3 words that go together in the following context, like :

> a.  Planetary 
> b.  Galactic 
> c.  Inter-Galactic

Can I use "pan-galactic" or "trans-galactic" in place for "inter-galactic"?

[P.S: I tried searching online for the prefixes pan- and tran- but was still not really clear about the usage.]

Comment: Well, only one is like having your brains smashed in by a slice of lemon wrapped round a large gold brick. Enjoy!

Comment: Yeah, there is non other like it! :-D .. like the Pan-Galactic Gargle Buster!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that all the three words can do well for a video-game, but FWIW here are the slight differences:

- pangalactic = involving/encompassing all the galaxies
- inter-galactic = between galaxies
- trans-galactic = across galaxies

Comment: Got it, Thanks!  So, what would you recommend for, say... a Championship? like,  pangalactic championship, intergalactic championship or trangalactic championship?

Cheers!

Comment: @dostiharise For a championship, I'd use intergalactic to mean that galaxies compete with each other (i.e. a championship **between** galaxies). For comparison: international championship, interstate championship, etc.

Comment: If you're being picky, _pangalactic_ is ambiguous, because it might mean _all the galaxies_ but it might mean _all the galaxy_, that is, _the whole of our one galaxy_.

Answer (score 4):

Of terms formed by prefixes *[trans-](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trans-)*, *[pan-](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pan-)*, *[inter-](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inter-)* attached to base *[galactic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/galactic)*, only *[intergalactic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/intergalactic)* ("Occurring between galaxies") unequivocally denotes involvement of multiple galaxies.

From wiktionary links in previous paragraph, *trans-* indicates "across, through, over, beyond, to or on the other side of, outside of".  One of the most common uses of  *trans-* is to denote "across the whole of", as in *[transcontinental](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/transcontinental)* ("Crossing, spanning a continent") and in the name *[Trans Global Highway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trans_Global_Highway)* ("a range of proposed highway systems that would link all six of the seven inhabited continents on Earth").  Following those examples, *trans-galactic* would mean "spanning the galaxy", involving one galaxy rather than several.

Prefix *pan-* is "A combining form meaning 'all'".  For example, *[Pan-Asian](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Pan-Asian)* means "Covering or representing all of Asia" and *[Pan-American](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Pan-American)* "Covering or representing all of the Americas (both North America and South America), particularly with respect to events involving representatives of most or all countries in the Americas".  Following those terms I am more inclined to interpret *pan-galactic* as "all of the galaxy" or "all the stars of the galaxy" rather than as "all the galaxies".

Prefix *inter-* indicates "among, between, amid, during, within, mutual, reciprocal".  Examples include *[intercontinental](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/intercontinental)* ("Taking place between two or more continent") and *[interstellar](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/interstellar)* ("between the stars" or "among the stars") and *[intergalactic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/intergalactic)* ("Occurring between galaxies").

Also consider term *multi-galactic*; prefix *[multi-](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/multi-)* indicates "Resembling, pertaining to many or many things".

Comment: Awesome! That was everything I need to know. 
Thanks a ton, for the detailed explanation!